# I just down loaded Opera browser why is it no longer pinned to my menu the next day?

Tags: icons, menu, opera

I just down loaded Opera browser yesterday. It worked all day but then today there is no longer a icon pinned to the menu? Where did it go? How can I get it back?

Comment: It may depend on how you installed it. I recommend installing the native `.deb` package, which I did with Martin Wimpress' `deb-get` tool. Install that, and then just type: `deb-get install opera-stable`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Dash (windows key) and search for Opera. Start it.

When started it will show an icon in the launcher. Now rightclick on the Opera launcher and choose "lock to laucher".

There are 2 possible launcher options:

1. lock to launcher
2. unlock from launcher

In case "lock to launcher" is shown the launcher will close when you close the application. When "Unlock from launcher" the icon will stick to the launcher when you close the application.

(this is valid for all launcher incons; not just Opera).